# Plotted Lines (Set to a certain value) Appear in Different Thickness on the Borders

Tags: matlab, plot

I was wondering why the thickness of the border lines on my simple grid plot are different on the left and top corners (than right and bottom) and they are all thinner than the inner lines with the following code in which I set the thickness the same for all (set(Z, 'LineWidth', 3)). I would so much appreciate your comments:

PS: Please note that the crowded "Z=..." bit on the code is just to define the lines and the fixation spot.

```
set(gcf,'doublebuffer','on');
set(gcf,'units','normalized','outerposition',[0 0 1 1]);
set(gcf,'Color',[1 1 1]);

k=1;
rannum1(1)=0;
rannum2(1)=0;
x_min=0; x_max=600; y_min=0; y_max=600;

r=[0 600]; s=[600 600]; m= [0 0]; n= [600 0];
Z=plot([r(1) s(1)], [r(2), s(2)] , '-black', [r(1) m(1)], [r(2), m(2)] , '-black', [m(1) n(1)], [m(2), n(2)] , '-black', [s(1) n(1)], [s(2), n(2)] , '-black', [(r(1)+s(1))/2 (((r(1)+s(1)+m(1)+n(1))/4)+rannum1(k))], [(r(2)+s(2))/2 (((r(2)+s(2)+m(2)+n(2))/4)+rannum2(k))], '-black', [(((r(1)+s(1)+m(1)+n(1))/4)+rannum1(k))  (m(1)+n(1))/2], [(((r(2)+s(2)+m(2)+n(2))/4)+rannum2(k)) (m(2)+n(2))/2], '-black', [(r(1)+m(1))/2 (((r(1)+s(1)+m(1)+n(1))/4)+rannum1(k))], [(r(2)+m(2))/2 (((r(2)+s(2)+m(2)+n(2))/4)+rannum2(k))] , '-black', [(((r(1)+s(1)+m(1)+n(1))/4)+rannum1(k)) (s(1)+n(1))/2],  [(((r(2)+s(2)+m(2)+n(2))/4)+rannum2(k)) (s(2)+n(2))/2], '-black', 300, 300, 'o', 'MarkerEdgeColor','none','MarkerFaceColor','r', 'MarkerSize',12);

set(Z, 'LineWidth', 3);
axis([x_min x_max y_min y_max]);
axis square
axis off
set(gca, 'visible', 'off', 'units', 'normalized', 'position', [0.200 0.230 0.60 0.60]);
```

Thank you very much!

PS: Playing around with the rendering options did not help completely.

inci

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lines of the outer box are thinner because of the drawing limits, i.e. try xmin=ymix=-5 and xmax=ymax=605. That is because of the lines being thicker than 1 px and centred on 0 or 600, thus the limit cuts off some extra pixles.